# How can I make a validation that depends on the value of another field with the StreamTransform Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

The fields are a select and the other is a field of identity card. It depends on what you select the field has a different validation.
I get the value of the select but when validating the field, it doesn't take the value

```html
final _idController=StreamController<String>.broadcast();
String type = '';
  // The controller to stream the final output to the required StreamBuilder
  final _typeId = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get typeId => _typeId.stream;

  // The controller to receive the input form the app elements
  final _query = StreamController<String>();
  Sink<String> get query => _query.sink;
  Stream<String> get result => _query.stream;

  // The business logic
  OtherChargesController() {
   result.listen((newType) {
      // Listen for incoming input
      type = newType; // Process the required data
      _typeId.sink.add(type); // Stream the required output
      
    });
   
    //Form State
  }


Stream<String> get id => _idController.stream.transform(type.contains('01') ? validPhysialId : type.contains('02') || type.contains('04') ? validaLegalAndNITEId : type.contains('03') ? validaDIMEXId : validaId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write listener for second field. 
While enter value in second field the attached listener will listen controller and there you can implement your logic of validation. 
Hint: Register your listener in initState(){}